# M2.3.1 - Remove currency symbol from price

Tags: magento2, price, currency, currency-symbol

Is it possible to get the price without currency symbol, or a way to put a div around the currency symbol to hide it with css?

```
$block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer())
```

If I remove the $block->formatCurrency I get the price without currency symbol, but a 1 will be added at the end of the price.

So I would like to put a div around the currency symbol and hide it with CSS.

Someone who can help me with that?

EDIT: I also want to add ,- behind the price.

Answer (score 2):

May be this will help you

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$currency = $objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\Currency');
$price = 100;
echo $currency->format($price, ['display'=>\Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL], false);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced a similar task and found this solutions:

1. For home page and category pages.

You need to override **app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\price\amount\default.phtml**.

In my case it was 20 line. The line looked like this:

```
><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()), ['span']) ?></span>
```

And now it was changed to this:

```
><span class="price"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getDisplayValue()) ?></span></span>
```

2. For product page.

You need to create **require-config.js** in **app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme** with content:

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        priceBox:'Magento_Catalog/js/custom-price-box',
    }
};
```

Then create your custom price box in **app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\web\js\custom-price-box.js**. The content is:

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box',
    'jquery/ui'
],
function ($, utils, _, mageTemplate) {

    'use strict';

    $.widget('customName.priceBox', $.mage.priceBox, {
        /*eslint-disable no-extra-parens*/
        /**
         * Render price unit block.
         */
        reloadPrice: function reDrawPrices() {
            var priceFormat = (this.options.priceConfig && this.options.priceConfig.priceFormat) || {},
                priceTemplate = mageTemplate(this.options.priceTemplate);

            _.each(this.cache.displayPrices, function (price, priceCode) {
                price.final = _.reduce(price.adjustments, function (memo, amount) {
                    return memo + amount;
                }, price.amount);

                price.formatted = price.final + ',-'; //you need to change this line, as example

                $('[data-price-type="' + priceCode + '"]', this.element).html(priceTemplate({
                    data: price
                }));
            }, this);
        },
    });

    return $.stagem.priceBox;
});
```

And my price now showing without currency symbol. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to get price without currency symbol by using below approach

Instantiate `\Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $priceCurrencyFormat` class in constructor and use below code

```
$this->priceCurrencyFormat->format($product->getPrice(), ['precision'=>0, 'display'=>\Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL], 0);
```

In second param of format() func you can also customize the price precision based on your requirement.

You could also use below code to get your result, but it is not a good approach

```
$objectManager    = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$priceCurrencyFormat = $objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\Currency');
$priceFormat = $priceCurrencyFormat->format($product->getPrice(), ['precision'=>0, 'display'=>\Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL], 0);
echo $priceFormat."-";
```

Comment: Hi, I can't find the file to edit. Are you sure is the correct path for Magento 2?

Comment: Directly editing the core file is not recommended, you should override the file in which you need your changes. In that overdid file (say you overdid any block file ) you can create the function with the above code and call it in your file.

Comment: I have updated my answer, placing those 4 lines of code in your desired files will give you your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You guys can use this extension.

https://marketplace.magento.com/extrembler-overridecurrencysymbol.html

Which is paid.

Thanks